# Wrapper function only sees itself?

Tags: c++, function, wrapper, identifier

Sorry for the vague title. I don't know how to phrase this issue.

I am practicing the use of pointers in C++ by rewriting a mergesort program by passing reference, but have run into an issue. To create a scratch array in a non-recursive method, I made the wrapper function...

```
void mergesort(int *low, int *high){
     int *barr = new int[high-low+1];
     mergesort(*low, *high, *barr);
}
```

...which in the end calls the function...

```
void mergesort(int *low, int *high, int *barr){
     int *mid;
     if(high - low < 2)
         return;
     int interval = high - low;
     *mid = interval/2;
     mergesort(low, mid, barr);
     mergesort(mid, high, barr);
     merge(low, high, barr);
}
```

...but I am getting the error **'mergesort': function does not take 3 arguments**. Well, no duh, Visual Studio. **Why does it not see the latter function instead of calling itself?**

I tried fixing the issue originally by throwing away clever coding conventions and just renaming the wrapper function `mergesortwrap(int *low, int *high)` and changing the call in the main, but then I get the error **'mergesort': identifier not found**. I am a Java kiddie. I don't understand this at all. Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: This is not related to your *current* problem, but you should probably go and learn a bit more about pointers in C/C++. In particular, if you have a variable declared as `int *my_int` learn the difference between using `myint` and using `*my_int`.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike in some other languages, free function declarations are not "hoisted" in C++. They are only available where they have been *previously* declared (or when you're inside a member function definition and are trying to name another member function).

That is why headers, which are typically included at the *top* of source files, conventionally have declarations:

```
void mergesort(int *low, int *high, int *barr);
void mergesort(int *low, int *high);
```

Then you can define them wherever you want but everywhere will be aware that these functions exist… including in the functions themselves.

A quick fix in your particular case is to swap the definitions around, since the overload taking three arguments doesn't need to know about the overload taking two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a **forward declaration** of the 3-legged overload before using it:

```
void mergesort(int *low, int *high, int *barr);

void mergesort(int *low, int *high){
     int *barr = new int[high-low+1];
     mergesort(*low, *high, *barr); // OK now
}
```

Alternatively, you can also define the 3-legged overload before the 2-legged one, but if the former would also call the latter, then you'd still have to forward declare it.

The only exception is when both functions are members of a class, because the whole class definition is being parsed before the member definitions.